# Google AdMob is not showing any impression of ads on my application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, ads

I am developing an application and now I wanted to implement ads in my application.
I have written the code and it is showing the test ads successfully. Test ads and real ads are operated through same channel, which means my code is correct.

Also my app is on play store and in next few updates I have planned to implement ads in it, but now I am facing this problem.

here is the sample of the code that I am using!

```
InterstitialAd interstitialAd = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blue);

   interstitialAd= new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    interstitialAd.show();
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            finish();
        }
    });
   }else{
       super.onBackPressed();
   }

}
```

Here is the image showing the number of request my application is making and also number of impressions :(

[Please Check the AdMob Result here!](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/99/b6/ed/99b6eda3e6775f7b421a6457427b056a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the solution.
The solution is nothing, when I was testing the application then their is no ads impressions, but when I released it on PS, then the ads impressions has started, so don't worry, when you publish your it starts showing the ads :)